# How to retain the space between the particular list items in Listview in QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a listview with some list items. But i need a space between the 2nd and 3rd list item in list view.

I have tried to set the height of the particular item in list view component.oncompleted(). In list view i can have around 30 items at that time if i scrolled to last item and moving up height property set in component.oncompleted has no effect. Is there any other way to retain the space between the 2nd and 3rd list item.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    color: "black"
    property var curritem
    property var items

    ListView
    {
        id:idlistview
        model:SampleListModel{}
        x:350
        y:200
        width: 700
        height: 500
        clip: true
        spacing: 10
        focus: true
        highlight: Rectangle
        {
            x: 85
            y: idlistview.currentItem.y
            width: 400
            height: 66
            color: "grey"
            Behavior on y
            {
                SpringAnimation{spring: 2;damping: 0.1}
            }
        }
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false

        delegate: iddelegatecomponent
        Component
        {
            id:iddelegatecomponent
            Item
            {
                id: iditem
                x: 100
                y: 250
                width: 400
                height: 50
                Text
                {
                    id: idtext
                    text: caption
                    color: "#FFFFFF"
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pixelSize: 26
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                   // anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with index, each delegate knows its index, for example:

```js
ListView {
    model:10
    spacing: 1
    focus: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Item {
        width: parent.width
        height: index == 3 ? 80 : 40
        Rectangle {
            color: Qt.darker(Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1.0))
            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            Text {
                text: "item" + index
                color: "white"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```